# What word do we use for a person who acts on behalf of a computer?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

For example, a chess player is playing against a computer program, but on a real-life chess board. Every time the computer makes a move, a human makes that move on the chess board on behalf of the computer. What title can we give to this person?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the body of your question. Is the human making the moves that another computer indicates (which is the title of your question)—or is the human an actual player who is making their own moves (which is the body of your question)? Or are you describing a situation where *both* things are the case—the player is playing both *against* ***and*** *on behalf of* the computer?

Comment: "a chess player is playing against a computer program" was in the body of my question. For further clarity I should have used "a human moves a chess piece for the computer". https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FctwVRJksjJ4%2Fhqdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DctwVRJksjJ4&docid=tFVK96hhTkwZjM&tbnid=snF2ZSoJ2CA3PM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiCpfXZ07zkAhWNdXAKHfYRA80QMwhcKAAwAA..i&w=480&h=360&itg=1&bih=821&biw=1280&q=garry%20kasparov%20vs%20deep%20blue&ved=0ahUKEwiCpfXZ07zkAhWNdXAKHfYRA80QMwhcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: The problem is that the person is both *opponent* ***and*** *attendant* (or any of the other words in the existing answer). There is no word that combines both of those ideas into one.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use the word *surrogate* (an elected substitute), or a synonym of the word.

- proxy - a person authorized to act as the deputy or substitute for another.
- intermediary - a person acting between persons, parties, etc.; serving as an intermediate agent
- delegate - a person designated to act for or represent another or others
- representative - a person or thing that represents another or others.

Comment: Please could you edit in definitions?